# AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute '__path__' - error when using virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a simple python script called 'process.py'. Written in Python3.

I have successfully setup a virtualenv. The script uses pymongo so I have pip-3.3 installed pymongo ok.

Now when I run

```
>python process.py
```

I get the following cryptic error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

File "process.py", line 3, in <module>
   import pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError as ConfigurationError
ImportError: No module named 'pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError'; pymongo.errors is not a package
```

Here is the top of the script:

```
import pymongo
import pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError as ConfigurationError
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

....
```

I am fairly new to Python. I really don't get what is going on here. The crazy thing is that 4 weeks ago it all worked fine!

All help gratefully appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have *only* python3 installed? Otherwise `python process.py` will probably use python2...

Comment: I have both python2.7 and python3.x installed. I created the virtualenv with -p /usr/bin/python3 flag and indeed when inside the virtualenv running 'python' brings up a python3.3 REPL.

Comment: I think the error is saying that Python could not import `pymongo.errors`. See [issue15767](http://bugs.python.org/issue15767). At the REPL, type `import pymongo; pymongo.__file__`. Does it point to the correct (Python3) installation of pymongo?

Comment: yes, it does point to /.../myproject/env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py

Comment: Ok, so I have commented out the import pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError line and the script now runs perfectly. 4 weeks ago it also ran perfectly. In the mean time I re-setup the virtualenv and re-installed pymongo. So obviously the latest version of pymongo makes the errors.Configuration import break. Just another day in Python Package management HELL. Seriously, what on Earth is going on here. 3 hours wasted.